# Building Boost for static linking (MinGW)

Tags: c++, boost, build, linker, bjam

I'm building Boost (I'm using System and FileSystem) for MinGW using bjam:

```
bjam --toolset=gcc stage
```

And it builds fine, but I want to be able to statically link to it (I have to have a single file for the final product) so I tried:

```
bjam --link=static --toolset=gcc stage
```

But I get the same output. Any ideas?

*edit* second question in a row I've answered moments after posting :p guess I'll leave this up here for others though.

```
bjam --build-type=complete --toolset=gcc stage
```

Will build both dynamic and static for sure.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think link is a property as opposed to an option for bjam. That means that there should be no -- before it.

This is my command line for building only static libraries (visual c++ though):

```
bjam install --toolset=msvc variant=release link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static
```

Mapping that to your original build command I would say it should look something like this:

```
bjam --toolset=gcc link=static stage
```

or perhaps:

```
bjam stage --toolset=gcc link=static
```

Try running

```
bjam --help
```

for more info on properties and options for bjam.

Answer (score 9):

Just want note that with the newer boost (Feb 2011) you need to build bjam as well now.. for some reason the current downloadable bjam doesn't work cleanly.

So first:

`cd ...\boost_1_45_0\tools\build\v2\engine\src`

`build.bat mingw`

Youll need to add bjam to the PATH (from control panel, not just on the cmd prompt). Then

`cd ...\boost_1_45_0\`

`bjam --build-type=complete --toolset=gcc stage`

My setup is Vista, Boost 1.45, MinGW 4.5, and building from cmd.exe not msys.

http://code-slim-jim.blogspot.com/2011/02/boost-in-vista-using-mingw-and-cmdexe.html

Comment: Thanks! The missing bjam was a surprise to me when updating my boost version recently.

Answer (score 0):

I have not built this myself in MinGW but I believe your first build will output both dynamic and static libraries and the second only static ones, so if you did not clean the build directories in between builds it will probably look the same.

When you write "I have to have a single file..." do you mean you need a single library containing all boost libraries? If so, I suspect you may have to 'ar' them together yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply, what I meant by "I have to have a single file..." is that I must have my executable, and no DLLs shipped with it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command line to build both the statically linked as well as the dynamically linked versions of boost:

```
bjam  "-sBUILD=debug release <runtime-link>static/dynamic <threading>multi" stage
```

This is done with visual c++ on windows YMMV.