# How to use 'boost_python-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib' in C++?

Tags: c++, boost-python

I am trying to use BoostPython to write a program in C++.

My presettings are:

a. Win32 Console Application.

b. Property->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories->C:\Python27\include;C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_54_0;

c. Property->Linker->General->Additional Library Directions->C:\Python27\libs;

d. Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express Version + Python 27 + Boost 1.54

And my code is like follows:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this code is with an empty main function. And I got an error message

> error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib'

I checked the installation of boost ('bootstrap.bat'+'bjam.exe'), and I've searched within the folder where boost library installed for 'boost_python-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib', but found nothing.

I looked for some similar posts, unlike my problem, the lib file they missed was with a prefix 'lib'. On the other hand, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881771/boost-1-53-python-fatal-error-lnk1104-boost-python-vc110-mt-gd-1-53-lib) is very similar to mine. But I found the OP made a mistake when he/her solve his/hers problem. That is, Boost is compatible with python 2.2 and its newer versions. And the rest of his answer is not helpful to me.

I guess this problem could because either I've done something wrong during installation, or I was wrong when I link the libs to my application.

Can anyone help me out of this? A detailed solution will be great. Many thanks. :)

==============================================================

EDIT:

I've reinstalled the Boost with a prebuilt binary file. Now I can link to the lib file the compiler asked for. However, new problems are raised. Now I have two new errors:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
>
> error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

When I comment out the line `#include <boost/python.hpp>`, the above errors are gone.

I really cannot figure out the reason. Can anyone help me with this? Many thanks.

Comment: Is the boost python lib in C:\Python27\libs? Or is it in a different directory? Have you built it?

Comment: @doctorlove I've looked into C:\Python27\libs, but there is no such a lib. Does that mean the boost is allright but there is something wrong with Python setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the error is raised because the Boost library was not properly installed in my computer. Actually, the key is bjam, and it must be run to build all these necessary libraries.

I would suggest anyone else that encounter with this problem, if you don't know how to run a bjam properly, go to search for a prebuilt binary file of Boost. That could save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You've added the C:\Python27\libs folder to you linker settings, but that doesn't have the boost files.

You need to run boost's `bjam` to generate the boost library files. Lots of boost is header only, but there are some libraries which you will need to build.

When you have done that you need to add the directory to

> "Property->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories"

Comment: I've ran 'bjam.exe' again and done some search online, and found that the lib is supposed to be at 'C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_54_0\stage\lib', but now it's not there. So it doesn't work.

Comment: That's a different question really. Did it report any errors? If so what? If there were no errors, it will have put them somewhere on your hard drive.

Comment: Yes, it reports errors. The only message is error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib'

Comment: By "it" I meant boost jam when you try to build the boost libraries.

Comment: I've deleted boost, and now am re-installing it.

Comment: That won't give you any libs. Instructions here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#simplified-build-from-source

Comment: I've tried to follow the link you sent. It turns out that the installation didn't generate the lib files that I need. I thus download a prebuilt binary setup file. Now the question in my post is gone. However, there are two new errors emerged, which are `"error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct"` and `"error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals"`. I find out this is due to that I included `boost\python.hpp`. When I comment the include line, the errors are gone. May I know how to solve it? Many thanks. :)

Comment: BTW, the above operations are carried out in a Win32 Console Application.