# boost library link error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, windows-7

I have a built boost library and linking is OK with

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
```

but when I add

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/date_timehpp>
```

I have link error

fatal error LNK1104: can not open the file "libboost_date_time-vc110-mt-s-1_55.lib"

I have a dynamic library configuration

why linker seeks static lib

I have libs in folder

...........\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_date_time-vc110-mt-1_55.lib

...........\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_date_time-vc110-mt-gd-1_55.lib

Comment: Give us full code. Yours doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are using /MT or /MTd option in C/C++/Code Generation/Runtime Library.
This issue was disscused in - 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628527/linker-error-lnk1104-with-libboost-filesystem-vc100-mt-s-1-49-lib)