# 2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-sgd-1_58.lib'

Tags: boost, cmake, msvc12

And no wonder as there is no such file in `...\boost_1_58_0\stage\lib`. How can I get one ? I only have:

```
boost_1_58_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-s-1_58.lib
boost_1_58_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc120-s-1_58.lib
```

in there. Tried to compile boost with various options ending up with tacking  `--build-type=complete` to it (the "poor man's" solution from [Linker error LNK1104 with 'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-s-1_49.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628527/linker-error-lnk1104-with-libboost-filesystem-vc100-mt-s-1-49-lib/27054853#27054853)) to get:

```
> b2 toolset=msvc threadapi=win32 link=static runtime-link=static \
variant=release address-model=32 --with-filesystem --with-locale --with-regex \
--with-system --with-iostreams --build-type=complete
```

the command line being suggested in the readme of the project that I am importing - still no joy. It is a CMake project I got into some pains to build an MSVS solution for.

NB: my problem was solved when looking carefully at the CMake gui:

[image]

I realized that it is the Debug configuration that did not build and sure enough when I right clicked on the "solution" > Configuration Manager > changed to a release build all was ok. Still the question remains - how do I get those libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-***sgd***-1_58.lib builds ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd need to have `runtime-link=static runtime-debugging=on variant=debug` in the b2 command line args to get `sgd`.

From the [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) about library naming on Windows (specifically the ABI tag portion):

> ABI tag: encodes details that affect the library's interoperability with other compiled code. For each such feature, a single letter is added to the tag:
>
> ```
> Key  |  Use this library when:                                |  Boost.Build option
> =====================================================================================
>  s   |  linking statically to the C++ standard library and    |  runtime-link=static
>      |  compiler runtime support libraries.                   | 
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  g   |  using debug versions of the standard and runtime      |  runtime-debugging=on
>      |  support libraries.                                    |
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  y   |  using a special debug build of Python.                |  python-debugging=on
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  d   |  building a debug version of your code.                |  variant=debug
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  p   |  using the STLPort standard library rather than the    |  stdlib=stlport
>      |  default one supplied with your compiler.              |
> ```

Comment: Wow thanks - are `variant=release` and `variant=debug` exclusive ? In other words would it be enough to just add `runtime-debugging=on variant=debug` in my command line above (I already have `runtime-link=static`)

Comment: I think if you leave `variant` out altogether it builds debug and release by default.  I also *think* (not sure) that it chooses `runtime-debugging=on` by default when it's building the debug version.  Basically, try running your original command without the `variant` flag.

Comment: Dropped the `variant` and sure enough`C:\_\boost_1_58_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-sgd-1_58.lib
C:\_\boost_1_58_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc120-sgd-1_58.lib` were added - (4 times bigger than the other variants) - closing :)

Comment: Hi, how do I set these command args in the visual studio 2013 properties? Do such options exist outside of running from the command line?