# Having problems with Boost library and Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, linker-errors

**Hello!**

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I recently tried to implement the Boost library in one of my projects, but that doesn't seem to be working. I always get problems with linking, and I always get the same error `1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib'`. (This one was for the

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

code. I get the same error for all the libraries I tried to link)

I downloaded the binaries the Boost webpage offered, and installed it.
I also tried adding in `C/C++ > General > Additional include Directory` settings the following:

```
C:\local\boost_1_66_0
```

and to the `Linker > General > Additional library Directory` settings I added

```
C:\local\boost_1_66_0\libs
```

And I turned off "Using Precompiled Headers". (the above were suggested by the Boost webpage)

The thread here "[Linker error LNK1104 with 'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-s-1_49.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628527/linker-error-lnk1104-with-libboost-filesystem-vc100-mt-s-1-49-lib)" also suggested changing my settings in `C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library` from MT/MTd to MD/MDd which I have already done. It also said something about a bjam.exe programme, which I have not found in my boost directories, whatsoever.

Despite my tries, again `LNK1104` ERROR. What should I do?

Comment: Did you verify that `libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib` exists in the folder you have added to your Additional library Directorys?

Comment: @drescherjm everything but the bjam.exe

Comment: So `libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib` does exist? Your reply does not seem that you verified the exact file name.

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake. I need the 32 bit folder, not the 64 one.... I actually installed the 64 one -_-. The files exist, but not the 32 bit ones. In my build I have "libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66.lib", not "libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib"

Comment: @drescherjm Again, I downloaded the 32 bit version, but again the same error!

Comment: Well at this point, unless someone can see what you're actually doing, I don't see a resolution to this issue except to tell you "you're doing something wrong".  I have used VS 2017 and boost with absolutely no issues.  The Additional Library Directory is set correctly, header file include set correctly, and no issues.

Comment: Maybe you did not set these settings  for every configuration. Remember the settings for each configuration is independent.

Comment: No, didn't fix the error

Comment: @drescherjm I am really sorry to be a bother! I was indeed wrong. At first glance the files I had and the ones the compiler asked for seemed identical. However, I had libboost_filesystem-vc**140**-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib not libboost_filesystem-vc**141**-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib.

Comment: The `vc140` versions are for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I am really dumb. Thank you again for your help and sorry for being a bother :D

Comment: I think it is a little confusing when the difference is between `vc140` and `vc141` in a long string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Visual Studio` is both a 32 bit and a 64 bit compiler, there are no less than 16 different types of a library that you can link with it, i.e. the combinations of:

- 32 bit or 64 bit,
- shared or static library,
- debug or release
- and single or multi threaded.

Also, since there are different version of both `boost` and `Visual Studio`, there are potentially many more combinations than the 16 above! Fortunately, `boost` supports auto linking with `Visual Studio`, see: [How Boost automatically includes libraries](https://codeyarns.com/2014/06/09/how-boost-automatically-includes-libraries/). So the filename in your linker error gives some clues as to precisely what type of `boost` library `Visual Studio` is searching for:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib'

According to the answers here: [How can I decode the boost library naming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715164/how-can-i-decode-the-boost-library-naming)
, `Visual Studio` is searching for multi-threaded, debug version of the `boost 1.66` `filesystem` library.

I also know from experience that `Visual Studio` static libraries start with `libboost_` while shared libraries start with `boost_` and someone changed the `boost` naming system in `boost 1.66` to add the size to the name (`-x32` or `-x64`), causing no end of trouble to existing build systems, e.g. [CMake](https://cmake.org/)!

So `Visual Studio` is still searching for a static, 32 bit version of `boost::filesystem`, despite changing your settings...

To fix it, either download the 32 bit static libraries or build your own boost libraries by following the instructions here: [Building boost for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838714/building-boost-1-65-0-vcvarsall-bat-not-found/45842161#45842161).

Note: regardless which option you choose, you'll still get the compiler warning:

> Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

because, the current version of `Visual Studio` was released after`boost 1.66`.
This is a common warning when using older versions of `boost` with newer compilers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I downloaded the correct version, but I had version 14.0, not 14.1 (I had libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib not libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib). I also built it to make sure it operates properly and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the \libs directory to the library paths add the \lib64-msvc-14.1 directory.

Comment: Did you add it for the correct configuration? Win32 (x86) builds need the lib32-msvc-14.1 directory while win64 builds need lib64-msvc-14.1. Personally I suggest making these changes under the view->Other windows->Property manager window.  That way they will be present for all projects you want to build.